# Ask Ubuntu website not working properly

Tags: discussion

Posted a question, received a response, but when i tried to reply there was no reply section to write my response just a comments box and a box saying "Answer Your Question"

I have used this site a lot but never had this problem before

First [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754414/input-incorrect-line-into-gedit) related to /etc/fstab gedit

Comment: Have you taken a look at the site tour? https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 5):

The format of Ask Ubuntu and other Stack Exchange sites is to ask questions, and receive answers to the question, which are created in the 'Your Answer' box. Other communication is done in comments, either on the original question, or on one of the answers to the question. The question you're asking about currently has no answers, only comments on the original question. You can respond to comments with comments, and can mention one other user in the comment string by using the @ symbol followed by their name such as @Arronical

As [bodhi.zazen](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/35795/bodhi-zazen) has noted below, any further information requested, is best included in the original question by using the 'edit' function (written in grey on the left hand side of the question). It's best to avoid getting in to long discussions in comments, as they're much less permanent than proper questions and answers

Comment: That, and it is generally a good idea to edit/update the question to provide requested information in comments rather then leaving information in the comments.